# open all csv files with different structure at the same time in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a text file and I am using pandas to process it. I am trying to skip the 1st few rows while opening the file. I don't have a fixed number of lines to be removed in different files (I am making a script) to use `skiprows` argument. but I know the line that would be the 1st line in new dataframe. so all the files would have this line in common and I want to remove any line before this line in all of them.

small example:

```
ID,Sample01
Owner,Administrator
ID,identifier
IL21R,6
CD84,21
KLRC2,9
TNFRSF11A,18
```

and here is the expected output:

```
ID,identifier
IL21R,6
CD84,21
KLRC2,9
TNFRSF11A,18
```

the common line among all files is:

```
ID,identifier
```

the following code works for the small example since there are only 2 line above the common line. how can I change the code to make it useful also for the files with more than 2 lines above the common line.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=2, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

> logic -  read the file in a list and find the index of ID,identifier.
>   Then use the value as skip rows.

```
   with open(r'file_path') as f:
        total = f.readlines()

    skip_value = total.index('ID,identifier\n')

    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(r'file_path',skiprows=skip_value, sep=',')
    print(df)
```